# Why my index.html page is loaded very slowly

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I tried to post my question on Sencha Forum but my account was disabled to post. I dont know why and sent msg to the administrator. And I need to figure it out asap.

I am using EXT JS4.0 MVC architecture developing my portal. Now, I have index.html which loads ext-all.css, ext-debug.js and app.js. App.js and its related files load some other 5 js files, most of them under view. Under firefox it takes 9-11 seconds. Now, those are simple files with simple data and logic.

Comment: Does it take long to load the actual files or does JavaScript execution take very long? The latter is not uncommon.

Comment: ExtJS in the past for me has been very slow, even under simple circumstances. If it's taking a while to load your JS files, your connection could be the issue (if your accessing a server other than your local machine).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on that page?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while for me and EXTJS, but did you try removing ext-debug.js?  As i remember, you don't want to keep that on your production version.